# What are the differents between S0CMX, S0C & S0U

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jstat

I am using jstat to show the survivor spaces. But I am confused with S0CMX, S0C & S0U. Can anyone tell me what the differents between these indexes are? And why S0C is always much less than S0CMX? Thanks!

```
$ jstat -gcnewcapacity 100142
NGCMN      NGCMX       NGC      S0CMX     S0C     S1CMX     S1C       ECMX        EC      YGC   FGC 
68157440.0 68157440.0 68157440.0 22718976.0 250880.0 22718976.0 249344.0 68156416.0 67657216.0   828     5

$ jstat -gcnew 100142
 S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U   TT MTT  DSS      EC       EU     YGC     YGCT  
268288.0 264704.0 211520.3    0.0  1  15 264704.0 67624448.0 66820880.8    872 1374.583
```

I printed with -gcnewcapacity & -gcnew, it shown S0CMX was much larger than S0C, at the same the TT was 1 while MTT was 15. Actually what confused me was why S0C didn't get a larger space to reduce tenured promotion?